# Connecting to blockchain on azure using web3.js and websocket

Tags: web3js, blockchain, microsoft-azure, websocket

right now, I am trying to write a service using web3 which will 'subscribe' to all 'perndingtransactions' on blockchain to perform further actions. web3 documentation says that 'Httpprovider' cant be used for subscription, instead 'Websocketprovider' should be used. Does anybody know how to enable websocket in Azure node?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using azure POA consortium you have already a websocket endpoint.

The url is available under deploiment outputs as shown in the picture below ::

[image]