# Cannot connect to Azure PoA Websocket

Tags: web3js, poa, microsoft-azure, websocket

Just like question [Connecting to blockchain on azure using web3.js and websocket](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55103/connecting-to-blockchain-on-azure-using-web3-js-and-websocket), I need to use websockets to capture events.

I have gotten my http and websocket endpoints from the deployment outputs page.

The http endpoint accepts a connection, the web socket endpoint does not.

The following code works 100% on ganache but says that the http connection is good and the ws connection is bad on Azure.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

async function wtf() {

    let web3http = new Web3(config.addrCurr);

    let accounthttp = web3http.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + config.privateKey);

    try { await web3http.eth.getTransactionCount(accounthttp.address); console.log("http good"); } catch (e) { console.log("http error: " + e); };

    let web3ws = new Web3(config.wsCurr);

    let accountws = web3ws.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + config.privateKey);

    try { await web3ws.eth.getTransactionCount(accounthttp.address); console.log("ws good"); } catch (e) { console.log("ws error: " + e); };

}

wtf();
```